# How do I troubleshoot unmet dependencies for bash and cpio on RHEL 6.6?

Tags: rhel, yum

I have installed many packages on my RHEL 6.6 server.  I am trying to install the dependencies of createrepo and createrepo itself.  I want to have a yum repository.  When I use `rpm -ivh *.rpm` in a directory with over 50 .rpms, I get this message of failure:

```
/usr/bin/bash is needed by glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.1x86_64
/usr/bin/cpio is needed by kmod-20-9.el7.x86_64
```

I installed packages for bash and cpio to try to get around this problem.  What should I do about these errors?  I thought I had all the dependencies.

Using the yum localinstall command failed too.  I tried creating a link (with ln -s) of the cpio and bash files to the locations that were referenced in the error messages.  I tried copying the cpio and bash files to those locations too. But that did not work either.  The error kept happening.

Comment: Why aren't you using yum?

Comment: The problems were less clear using yum.  rpm's error messages were much more clear.

Comment: Are CentOS 7 rpms the equivalent to RHEL 6 rpms?  Sometimes I inherit a RHEL system that needs rpms but it lacks a subscription to official RHEL rpms.

Comment: No they are not. CentOS 6 packages are the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that you should install the packages that provide those facilities, packages which should be compatible with your current release. Currently you have no package installed (or a package in the transaction that you are initiating via `rpm -ivh *.rpm` ) which provides `/usr/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/cpio`. If you would have the suitable packages installed, then rpm would not show those dependency errors. You can query which installed package provides those facilities via `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/cpio /usr/bin/bash`

On a related note, it does not affect rpm dependencies if you create a symlink at that location, as rpm only evaluates through the `Provides` tags of the installed packages.

It seems to me your issue comes from the fact that you try to install el7 packages on an el6 server.